# how do I say ''I do not know, I did not do anything to anyone'' in russian?

Tags: перевод

I guess is не знаю, я ничего не сделал никому or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Something like "*Не знаю, я ничего никому не делал.*"

While the word order is relatively liberal in Russian, for emphasis it's a bit better to put the verb last.

The choice of the verb (*сделал* vs *делал*) depends on whether you need Perfective aspect vs Imperfective one.

The Imperfective aspect can be (roughly) translated back into English using Continuous Tense, as in "I wasn't doing anything", whereas Perfective aspect can be translated using Perfect Tense (Present or Past, depending on context), although such distinction is not direct.  So your choice should really depend on whether you consider the action complete and its result observable (and in case of a negative sense, *would be* observable, *had it taken place*), or it's an action without a specific outcome (or *supposed outcome*).

Comment: yes I get it, but how do I know where to use imperfective and perfective??it's hard to understand though :/

Comment: It is hard, and I've tried expanding on it in my latest edit.

Comment: @russsss On Russian vs English tenses http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/is-it-possible-to-translate-english-tenses-into-russian-tenses

Answer (score 0):

In a conversation, the answers would probably be
- Я не знаю, я ничего никому не делал.
- Я не знаю, я ничего никому не сделал.
- Я не знаю, я никому не причинил зла.
- Я не знаю, я никому не причинял зла.
They all have same meaning " I don't know, I did not do anything to anyone."